# VB.Net class property specifying an object?

Tags: vb.net, object, properties

I'm currently writing a HMI for an automated machine in VB.Net 2010. I have a custom class that turns a Border green or red depending on the value of an input on a remote I/O module.

The connection to the remote I/O module is through a COM object provided by the manufacturer. I have three remote connections, lets' call them g1, g2, and g3. They're of type `Manufacturer.ConnectionObject`.

I would like to specify, using a property that I can set in XAML, that instances of `MyCustomBorder` use g1, g2, or g3. Unfortunately, setting up a Property called `g` and typing 'g1' into the property field results in the message "Property value is not valid. Details: Property 'g' does not support String to Value conversion."

So, instead, I am left to manually set (during program startup), every single instance of `MyCustomBorder`:

```
CustomBorder1.g = g1
CustomBorder2.g = g3
CustomBorder73.g = g1
```

... and so on.

I am told I need to implement a converter between String and the custom class, `Manufacturer.ConnectionObject`, but I have no idea how to accomplish this, especially since `Manufacturer.ConnectionObject` is part of a closed-to-me COM object.

Help, anyone? Thanks!

Comment: What type are you trying to convert to? Are you trying to convert a `ConnectionObject` directly to a `String`?

Comment: I'm trying to type a string into the property window (i.e. In the wysiwyg XAML editor) to select a specific ConnectionObject to be utilized by that instance of MyCustomBorder.

Comment: I think the wrapper approach is best then and set the property value setter choose the correct link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to directly bind a COM object into WPF is likely just going to cause you a lot of headaches.  As a first step I would define a WPF friendly class which wraps instances of `Manufacturer.ConnectionObject` and bind that instead to WPF

```
Class MyConnectionObject 
  Public Manufacturer.ConnectionObject _connection

  Public Property Value As String 
    Get
      ' Return _connection as a String
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

Comment: This sounds like an approach I can manage. I'd have to create an instance of this new class for each instance of ConnectionObject?

Comment: @evilspoons based on your recent comment I think you want one instance which wraps all 3 and then let value select which one is active and is bound to by the custom border

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx